# Knockout computed not updating using observable array

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

I have the following ViewModel:

```
function vm(model) {

    var self = this;

    var Create = function (data) {
        var order = ko.utils.extend(data, {});
        order.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
        return order;
    }

    self.orders = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, {
        create: function (options) {
            return Create(options.data);
        }
    });

    self.FirstPrice = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return parseFloat(self.orders()[0].Price());
    });
}
```

When the page is loaded the "FirstPrice" is updated normally, but after change the Price on first row of "orders" array, the "FirstPrice" remains the first value after page load.

What is missing?

* I removed some lines of code to simplify the example

Thanks

Comment: I believe `self.orders` needs to be an observable array.

Comment: Yes, it is. ko.mapping.fromJS converts a object to an observable array. I'm using it in MVC ;)

Comment: How are you changing the Price observable?

Comment: Couple things 1) Did you debug the purecomputed property and check if the code even gets called? There is a difference between purecomputed and computed observables. 2)If it is hitting the computed code, does the self.orders collection have the right/updated data. 3) Are you changing the price value using code or through UI? If its through code, make sure you don't do something like .price = xyz since its an observable. Some of these might be obvious to you but just for my info.

Comment: Hi. 1) Yes, I checked with an alert and it's being called only after page loads. I tested the computed observable too with same result. 2) After the page load the data is updated right. 3) I'm changing price value through UI. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem is that I'm using the inputmask in bound input.

There is a workahound to this:
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/wiki/HOWTO:-Integration-with-Knockoutjs

Sorry for not put the HTML where I used the observable in the question, this could help you to help me ;)

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).  In particular, this section:

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are *in* the array,
>   *not* the state of those objects

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I saw some other questions with this text reference, but it's not for my case, cause the Price property is an observable too. And my code works after page load.

Comment: I read the documentation and there is "...Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish"